# What might a moderator do to a trolling/spamming account

Tags: discussion, moderation, spam

I've come across a trolling/spam post by a user with no other contributions to the site.

I have flagged this post for moderator attention, but I'm curious: what might a moderator do in this kind of situation.

Comment: Also: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11598/do-spam-only-posting-users-get-deleted

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When an account is created with the sole purpose of trolling, spamming, etc, we generally destroy the account. This (as well as deletions of posts by [spam flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032/214632)) feeds information into a system which makes it more difficult for such people to continue posting their drivel on the site. There is evidence that upwards of 80% of all spam *attempted* to be posted to the site is **blocked** (and therefore is seen by no-one).

Comment: Before pressing the "Let fly the nukes" button, do you raise a long sword and yell "I HAVE THE POWEERRRRRR!!!!!!" as well?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I tried it, but I don't know how [He-Man](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dJolYw8tnk) does it; the lightning fried me up real good.

Comment: Wait, don't you have the powers of Grayskull?

Comment: Oops... I knew there was something I needed to get from Willie before he left.